# flutter What's the difference AppBarTheme "color" and "backgroundColor"?

Tags: flutter

color: Colors.transparent,

backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

Color and background color have the same effect.
What's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, `color` is a deprecated value and you should use `backgroundColor`.

If you look at the code of the `AppBarTheme` you will read:

```dart
  /// This property is deprecated, please use [backgroundColor] instead.
  ///
  /// Obsolete property that overrides the default value of
  /// [AppBar.backgroundColor] in all descendant [AppBar] widgets.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [backgroundColor], which serves this same purpose
  ///    as this property, but has a name that's consistent with
  ///    [AppBar.backgroundColor].
  ///  * [AppBar.backwardsCompatibility], which forces [AppBar] to depend
  ///    on this obsolete property.
  @Deprecated(
    'This property is no longer used, please use backgroundColor instead. '
    'This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre.',
  )
  Color? get color => backgroundColor;

  /// Overrides the default value of [AppBar.backgroundColor] in all
  /// descendant [AppBar] widgets.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [foregroundColor], which overrides the default value for
  ///    [AppBar.foregroundColor] in all descendant widgets.
  final Color? backgroundColor;
```

You can also see the code on the [Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2bd3e0d914854aa8c12e933f25c5fd8532ae5571/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart#L84-L110).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both of them, background value by default equals the color value. So, if you need custom app bar color on a specific page you can use the background-color